# Dynamic item list in Azure Workbooks

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks

Is it possible to have data driven layout in Azure Workbooks?

For each row of a Kusto query, I'd like to add a tile to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to have a single query generate many visualizations in workbooks (yet!)

There are some options:

1. you could use a visualization like "tiles" which creates an item for each row, and you can configure the various parts of the tile to get info from different columns.

presuming you literally mean "Azure Dashboard" here when you say dashboard:

2. (more manual) you could create a parameter that returns all those values, and then configure a subsequent query to reference the selected value to generate the visualization you want, and manually pick a value, pin the chart to the dashboard, repeat for each value you want pinned.
3. (more technical) you could create the visualization you want, and pin it to a dashboard.  then download the dashboard as json, and copy+paste the pin, but modify the query/parameter values in the dashboard, then upload it as a new dashboard?